# What is causing this accordion nav to lose browser default focus?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility

What is causing this accordion nav to lose browser default focus?

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <button aria-controls="collapseTwo" aria-selected="false" data-target="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse">Display</button>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
                <li class="iso-btn" data-filter=".desktop">
                    <a href="#">Desktop</a>
                </li>
                <li class="iso-btn" data-filter=".mobile">
                    <a href="#">Mobile</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Chrome, if I tab through the buttons with all CSS removed, focus is shown clearly on each button. I've gone through process of elimination with my CSS but I must be missing something - there needs to be default browser focus on the button when tabbed.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? HTML structure? Bootstrap? CSS?

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32544/

Comment: seems fine to me.

Comment: Chrome 58 / Win10, works for me. Focus goes to each link. Any chance you have some assistive tech or other add-ons interfering?

Comment: Tried it with Chrome 57 / OSX 10.11 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Works OK on Chrome 57 / Windows 8. There is no reason this should not work. Once you figure it out, you should also consider bringing an extra layer of accessibility to Bootstrap with Paypal's Accessibility Plugin: https://github.com/paypal/bootstrap-accessibility-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordion buttons should be using the `aria-expanded` attribute instead of `aria-selected` as shown.  Use of `aria-selected` is not valid on button roles and a false state can be confusing to the browser if not part of a selectable list.  For example, tabbing to a single-selection control usually will land on the selected item in the list and ignore the non-selected items.

See the [ARIA discussion of the `aria-selected` state](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-selected) for a discussion of user agent focus and other details, and also the [section on accordions in the ARIA Authoring Practices document](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#accordion).

Note that you should also be using an appropriate heading tag on your panel header for more accessible navigation.